# Convert time in PHP from gmt offset

Tags: php, datetime, timezone, gmt, date-conversion

For example i have a time string of "11:00" and and gmt offset string of "+02:00".

How can i combine the two to make the conversion in PHP?

Here is my current code:

```
$time = $row->time;

//Get users gmt setting

$timezone = $this->_get_gmt();

//calculate correct time here

$time = ; //whatever i have to do.
```

All answers appreciated.

Comment: Do you now Timezone or only offset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i P', '11:00 +02:00');
$date->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('GMT'));
echo $date->format('H:i');
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/blwycO)

This:

1. Creates a DateTime object with the time and offset
2. Converts the timezone to GMT
3. Echo's out the time in GMT

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `DateTime` object to do that

```
$date = new DateTime('Your Time String here');
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('GMT'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP') . "\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$time = $row->time;

$timezone = $this->_get_gmt();

$time = date( "H:i:s", strtotime( $time )+ $timezone * 60 * 60 )
```

assuming that `$time` is in time format: eg. 14:30, and `$timezone` is offset number eg. 2.